# Uploading multiple (keys) images with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a structure like,

```
[
  {
    _id: 62872,
    images: [''],
    services: [
      {
        _id: 67897,
        image: ''
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I worked with `upload.array("images")` in the middleware. But I don't exactly know how to work in this above situation. My question is how to parse or how to write middleware that accepts both images and image via multer?

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: Just edited. I would like to know how to parse both images and image.